# Repairing a shower drain - will this work?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I'm not that great a plumbing, but I'm researching whether this will work or be a problem. Below are 2 crude diagrams. The first is what I can implement, the 2nd would be extremely difficult for reasons too hard to explain.

This is in a 1986 mobile home. There is no code requirements where I live.

I'm guessing the weight of the water dropping is what propels it through a standard trap, but I really don't know. The question is can it propel through the inverted trap if it is lower than the horizontal pipe coming from the shower?

```
          vent                         |                     |
          valve                        |                     |
          |  |                         |        shower       |
          |  |                         |        drain        |
----------|  |----------floor-------------------|  |---------------------
          |  |                   _______________|  |
          |  |     __________    |  _______________|
          |  |     |  ____  |    |  |
          |  |     |  |  |  |    |  |
 main_____|  |_____|  |  |  |____|  |
 drain________________|  |__________|
 pipe
                                       

A better way, but nearly impossible to implement:                                       
                                                       
          vent                         |                         |
          valve                        |                         |
          |  |                         |          shower         |
          |  |                         |          drain          |
----------|  |----------floor---------------------|  |----------------------
          |  |       ___________________________  |  |
          |  |       |  _____________________  |  |  |   
          |  |       |  |                   |  |__|  |
          |  |       |  |                   |________|
          |  |       |  |
 main_____|  |_______|  |
 drain__________________|
 pipe
```

Comment: The problem with your 1st diagram is that the pipe to the right of the hump will *always* be full of water - it'll never drain, and without a *lot* of flow any solids are going to collect there and block the pipe - sooner rather than later. Why can't you just put the pipe in straight without the hump?

Comment: Is it not possible to connect to the vent valve higher up?